# How to have output repeat in a single vertical line?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to have player input continuously print in a vertical line each time a new input is entered. For some reason, this outputs a space the size of the entire input each time a new value is put in. I have no idea why this would be happening, as I believe the code never tells it to add such a space.

I have tried replacing the cursor position and refreshing the page each time but that has not worked. I have searched for solutions but have not found any. I am using the `ncurses` library and at this point I feel as though I must be overlooking something.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <ncurses.h>

void initialize()
{
    initscr();
    clear();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
}

int main()
{

    initialize();

    char input;
    bool turn = true;
    short int x, y = 0;

    while (turn) {
        ;
        input = getch();
        ;
        cout << "You entered: " << input << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**This is the Output:**

```
                                                            You entered: d
                                                                          You entered: j
        You entered: w
                      You entered: i
                                    You entered: d
                                                  You entered: j
                                                                You entered: a
                                                                              You entered: i
            You entered: w
                          You entered: j
                                        You entered: a
                                                      You entered: d
                                                                    You entered: i
  You entered: w
                You entered: j
                              You entered: d
                                            You entered: i
                                                          You entered: d
                                                                        You entered: d
```

**It should be:**

```
You entered: d
You entered: d
You entered: d
You entered: d
You entered: d
You entered: d
You entered: d
```

Comment: You are using standard stream `std::cout` not ncureses.  Please read [ncureses guide](http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html)

Comment: Mixing curses and iostreams doesn't work all that well. Pick and use one.

Comment: The reason I am using both ncurses and iostream is so that I am able to pause in between getting inputs. Is there a way to do this using ncurses?

Comment: Looks like you need '\n\r' instead of endl

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `cout` and `curses` doesn't work well, since the latter initializes the terminal to *raw* mode and simulates *raw* or *cooked* (e.g., [**`cbreak`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak)) mode.  `cout` doesn't know anything about that, and proceeds on the assumption that output is *"cooked"* (i.e., newline is translated to carriage return and line-feed).

That's related (but not really the same) as [`nl` and `nonl`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS) (again, curses simulates things).

If you really **have** to mix the two, you'll have to end every line with `\r\n` and do flushes to ensure that the output is complete.  But since the output using `cout` also confuses curses about where the cursor is (making curses put text in the wrong place on the screen), you'd only do this temporarily, to debug a program.